# Url launcher cant paste # symbol in dialpad from my Flutter App

Tags: flutter, url, flutter-dependencies

I have connected my Raised button in my Flutter app with url launcher in order to directly paste a code to the dial pad, but all the code pastes except # symbol. I tried by just putting # but still it doesnt pastes there. Following is the code

```
onPressed: (){
              launchURL('tel:*443#');
            }
```

All the code perfectly pastes in dial pad except # symbol. What I should do in order to paste complete code with # symbol. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Messed around and got something to work!

```
onPressed: () async {
  String encodedHash = Uri.encodeComponent("#");
  final url = "tel:*123$encodedHash";
  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    await launch(url);
  } else {
    print('not happening');
  }
},
```

Comment: It works perfectly fine that way. Thank you so much. But when I use an object with it, it doesnt work. `String encodeHash = Uri.encodeComponent('#');
                  launchURL('tel:${package.code} $encodeHash');`

Comment: In my code, launchURL is actually a function which contains if else statement as you mentioned in your code sir